# where does unique_ptr live?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, c++11, macports

I'm trying to compile some code (below) using gcc 4.6.2 on OSX 10.6.5. It's trivial; but the compiler cannot find unique_ptr.

```
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::unique_ptr<bar> foo(new bar(0));
}
```

I compile as such:

```
c++ main.cpp -o ./bin/main -std=gnu++0x -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wno-long-long -Wno-deprecated -O3 -ansi -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/include -I/opt/local/include
```

I tried explicitly including bits/unique_ptr but that leads me to an error saying **GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X** is undefined. Huh? As you can see above, I explicitly ask for gnu++0x. I've also tried "-std=c++0x" with identical results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your command has `-ansi` (which is equivalent to `-std=c++98`), and this overrides `-std=c++0x`. Try removing it.